# Call ('cal') results in error

Tags: windows, python-3.x, command-line

learning python has been a day and night goal for about two years and I have landed my first Python, Sql, Excel and now MongoDb job.

Yeahhh!

This is a different kind of hard, in creating tooling for sorting and sifting thru many file types to format clean and import data.

While doing this I'm still trying to expand my skill set to be more efficient with CMD and since we used a ton of CMD line stuff via Anaconda.

I found this tutorial... but it generates an error.

https://www.sitepoint.com/5-common-problems-faced-by-python-beginners/

On step 3
3. Executing an External Command through Python, I ran it and got an error.

```
>>> call('cal')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
>           with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in **init**
>           restore_signals, start_new_session)
>         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute
>           startupinfo)
>       FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Is this something with the tutorial that was depricated or 'you forgot' something?

Thanks in advance.

Windows7, VMware, Python3, Anaconda, Pycharm.

Comment: On my Windows pc, there is no "cal" program.

Comment: I believe the cal is python standard type item.
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/calendar.html

Comment: You're trying to execute an external command `cal`, but your computer doesn't have that command available.  `cal` isn't part of Python

Comment: `cal` is a Linux program but isn't on Windows. To test your program on Windows, try `call('calc.exe')`. That should launch the calculator program.

Comment: Yes that loads the calculator, but isn't there a calendar(cal) function within windows?

Currently I can only find 3rd party stuff.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/gyaC9N0NXQ8
and 
http://gnuwin32.sf.net/

Really wish we could just use unix vs windows.

Does anybody in tech specify on your resume or during a job interview that you won't work on windows?